# What is the validation expression for following e-mail format in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio, validation

I am trying to validate a text field where user have to enter the email address following format: firtsname.lastname@companyname.com

1) It must end with  `.com`. No numbers are allowed anywhere in the email-address. For example a valid email adderss: `fredric.william@gmail.com`

2) invalid email: `fredricwilliam@cool.com`

3) invalid email: `fredric19.william@cool.com`

Code that I am trying:

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorEmail" runat="server"
         ErrorMessage="Invalid Email !"  ForeColor="Red"
        ControlToValidate="emailtxt" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view detailed explanation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf(v=vs.110).aspx)  from Microsoft.
Let me give you two sample regular expression, so you can create your own or modify the below.

**Expression 1:**

> (([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@

Matches the user name part of an email address. This expression part is matched as follows:

`([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+)` - matches the dot separated user name groups (i.e. John.Connor of John.Connor@test.maildomain.com).
Rules: There should be at least two dot separated groups, each group should contain at least one alphanumeric character or '-', '_' characters and the '.' character at the end except the most right to the @-sign group.

or `([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,})` - matches the single (without '.' characters) user name (i.e. Max-White of Max-White@test.maildomain.com).
Rules: If the user name part consists of only one character, it should be a word character (a to z or A to Z) or there should be at least two alphanumerical, underscore or minus characters.

`@` - matches the @-sign of an email address.

**Expression 2:**

> (([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]).([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]).
>   ([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]).([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}

Matches the host part of an email address, if the host in the email address is represented as an IP-Address. As you can see, this expression part has four identical repeating groups each of them is used to match first up to the fourth octet of an IP-Address respectively. The whole expression part is matched as follows:

`([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.` - matches one of the first three octets of an IP-Address in the email string (i.e. 195.250.101. of John.Connor@195.250.101.219).
Rules: Optional first character '0' to '1' and optional second character '0' to '9' mandatory third character '0' to '9' OR mandatory first characters '25' and mandatory third character '0' to '5' OR mandatory first character '2' and mandatory second character '0' to '4' and mandatory third character '0' to '9' AND mandatory '.' character at the end of the octet group.

`([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])` - matches the last fourth octet of an IP-Address in the Email string (i.e. 219 of John.Connor@195.250.101.219).
Rules: The same as for the first three octets with the exception of '.' character at the end.

`{1}` - match a string, which contains only one "four-octet" group right after the @-sign.